# what is the use of muc_filter_message hook added in 15.07

Tags: ejabberd

Could you please tell the use of `muc_filter_message` hook added in 15.07?

I am trying to some changes in muc_room which uses this hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`muc_filter_message` and `muc_filter_presence` are new API used to filter / transform message or presence packet send to MUC before they are broadcasted to other users.